# JOLT - Flattening a simple JSON array

Tags: json, jolt

I want this:

```
{
  "DATA": [
    {
      "SPEED" : "hi",
      "ANGLE" : "180",
      "GRIT" : "2000"
    },
    {
      "SPEED" : "mid",
      "ANGLE" : "180",
      "GRIT" : "2000"
    },
    {
      "SPEED" : "lo",
      "ANGLE" : "180",
      "GRIT" : "2000"
    }
  ]
}
```

To become this:

```
{
  "SPEED" : "hi",
  "ANGLE" : "180",
  "GRIT" : "2000"
},
{
  "SPEED" : "mid",
  "ANGLE" : "180",
  "GRIT" : "2000"
},
{
  "SPEED" : "lo",
  "ANGLE" : "180",
  "GRIT" : "2000"
}
```

But with this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DATA": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

I get this:

```
{
  "SPEED" : [ "hi", "mid", "lo" ],
  "ANGLE" : [ "180", "180", "180" ],
  "GRIT" : [ "2000", "2000", "2000" ]
}
```

I'm very new to JOLT and since I can't find any documentation, I come to you for help.
Stackoverflow won't let me post this question since it contains mostly code, but that lies in the nature of this question, namely describing what input I have, what I want it to be and what I've tried.

EDIT:

@Pratik Jaiswal

Thanks for your answer, but it looks like I can do the same with

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DATA": {
        "*": {
          "@": ""
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

This doesn't remove the outer brackets, though. Is that even possible with JOLT? Or do I just have to get rid of them in another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "DATA": {
    "*": {
      "SPEED": "[&1].SPEED",
      "ANGLE": "[&1].ANGLE",
      "GRIT": "[&1].GRIT"
    }
  }
}
}
]
```

Test the spec here http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception